# Getting a fixed length token

Tags: graphviz, javacc

I am trying to write a javacc parser to read [GraphViz xdot format](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#a:xdot) files.  This file format has a pretty regular syntax, but I am having difficulty figuring out how to get tokens for the extended part of it.

The issue is that some of the tokens are preceded by a length value that states how long the token is, and some parameters have a length value that specifies how following tokens are required.

Here is an example:

```
graph [_draw_="c 9 -#fffffe00 C 7 -#ffffff P 4 0 0 0 13095 1541.31 13095 1541.31 0 ",
    bb="0,0,1541.3,13095",
    rankdir=LR,
    size="12,12",
    xdotversion=1.7
];
```

The extended part that I am having a problem with is the quoted string following the `_draw_=` token.  Within this string the first number 9 indicates the length of the next token following the '-' start character.  In case the token is a series of characters surrounded by whitespace (easy to define the token), but in other cases these following tokens may have embedded blanks, so I think it would be impossible to define an all-purpose regex.

Also, following the first 'P' character within this string is a 4, which indicates that 4 pairs of numbers follow.  How can the parser know to use this number to get the next 8 number tokens, or should the token manager just return the 8 number string somehow?

I know I can grab the entire contents of the string as a single chunk and then manually parse it in java (not using javacc) using some string matching.  However I was wondering if there is some technique to do this in javacc.

I suspect that after reading the length token I need to switch to a different lexical state, and within that match every character with a `MORE` modifier, and have a lexical action to switch back to a `TOKEN` state after the required count is met.  Is this along the right track?  How do I indicate that the token is complete in the lexical action?

Also, do I have to worry about `LOOKAHEAD`? (I think not if I do all this in the token manager)

I will follow up with some code once I figure out what to do.

Comment: I think your idea of using MORE  is perfect. Why not implement it and then answer your own question. There is no need to worry about LOOKAHEAD.

Comment: To indicate the end of a token you use a TOKEN production. So when there is one more character expected, switch to a state where any character  is a TOKEN.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it to work.  I decided to do this in a lexical action rather than with `MORE` processing, it just seemed more straightforward this way.  Also, I split the lexing/parsing in to two parts to make things simpler:

1. First parse out the strings containing the extended syntax, and then
2. parse these strings with the extended syntax in a second pass.

As for getting the tokens based on a length prefix, the first part was to define the tokens representing the commands:

```
<Extended>   TOKEN :
{
        <LINECOLOR:       "c"> { singleCount = 1; }
      | <FILLCOLOR:       "C"> { singleCount = 1; }
      | <FONT:            "F"> { singleCount = 2; }
      | <TEXT:            "T"> { singleCount = 5; }
      | <TEXTCHARS:       "t">
      | <SPLINE:          "B"> { coordCount = 1; }
      | <FILLEDSPLINE:    "b"> { coordCount = 1; }
      | <FILLEDELLIPSE:   "E">
      | <UNFILLEDELLIPSE: "e">
      | <POLYLINE:        "L"> { coordCount = 1; }
      | <FILLEDPOLYGON:   "P"> { coordCount = 1; }
      | <UNFILLEDPOLYGON: "p"> { coordCount = 1; }
      | <STYLE:           "S"> { singleCount = 1; }
}
```

I added statements in the lexical actions to indicate where the length token would occur after the command token.  In most cases it was the first token after the subcommand, but in some cases there were other intervening tokens that needed to be parsed first.

Next is to define the token to match the length count.  When triggered to consume the length specified token, the lexical action then decoded the length count and consumed the appropriate number of characters from the input buffer.  After getting the correct data, it switches the token image and type as appropriate.  This token also matches number strings in the default lexical state.

```
/*
 * Special number token.  Normally just grabs a number.
 * In the Extended lexical state can grab a fixed length
 * string or a list of coordinate pairs.
 */
<DEFAULT,Extended> TOKEN:
{
        <#NUM: (["0"-"9"]) >
    | <NUMBER: (<NUM>)+ | (<NUM>)* "." (<NUM>)+ | (<NUM>)+ "." (<NUM>)* >
    {
        if (curLexState == Extended && singleCount-- == 1) {
            // Get a single fixed length parameter
            int len = Integer.parseInt(matchedToken.image);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                while (input_stream.readChar() != '-')
                   { /* Do nothing */; };
                for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
                sb.append(input_stream.readChar());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new TokenMgrError(true, curLexState, input_stream.getLine(), input_stream.getColumn(), sb.toString(), (char)0, TokenMgrError.LEXICAL_ERROR);
            }

            matchedToken.image = sb.toString();
            matchedToken.endLine = input_stream.getEndLine();
            matchedToken.endColumn = input_stream.getEndColumn();
            matchedToken.kind = SINGLE;
        }
        if (curLexState == Extended && coordCount-- == 1) {
            // Get a list of coordinate pairs
            int len = Integer.parseInt(matchedToken.image);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                for (int i=0; i<len*2; i++) {
                char c;
                while ((c=input_stream.readChar()) == ' ')
                    { /* Do nothing */; };
                if (i>0) sb.append(" ");
                do
                    {sb.append(c);}
                while
                    ((c=input_stream.readChar()) != ' ');
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new TokenMgrError(true, curLexState, input_stream.getLine(), input_stream.getColumn(), sb.toString(), (char)0, TokenMgrError.LEXICAL_ERROR);
            }

            matchedToken.image = sb.toString();
            matchedToken.endLine = input_stream.getEndLine();
            matchedToken.endColumn = input_stream.getEndColumn();
            matchedToken.kind = COORDS;
        }
    }
}
```

The special tokens had to be declared, as well as the variables that held the countdown to the token to decode:

```
/*
 * Special extended token identifiers
 */
<Extended> TOKEN:
{
      <COORDS: <NUMBER>>
    | <SINGLE: <NUMBER>>
}

TOKEN_MGR_DECLS:
{
    /*
     * These keep track of where the length prefixed strings
     * and coordinate pairs start in the extended xdot commands.
     * Set these values in the lexical actions for the sub-command
     * definitions.
     */
    int singleCount = -1;;
    int coordCount = -1;;
}
```

That was actually pretty easy once I understood how lexical actions worked and what can be done with the token manager API.

To make use of this in the parser, switch to the Extended lexical state and use productions like:

```
<LINECOLOR> color=<SINGLE>
```

or

```
<UNFILLEDPOLYGON> scoords=<COORDS>
```

or

```
<TEXT> sx=<NUMBER> sy=<NUMBER> sj=<NUMBER> sw=<NUMBER> label=<SINGLE>
```

That is it.  It seems to work well.

The only drawback to the way that I have done this is that `SKIP` processing will not occur on the characters that I manually read from the input stream, so I have to take care of whitespace (not fully implemented in my code example).